# Undo a git squash rebase

Tags: git

I messed up squashing my commits into one commit.

If the commits went

> NOTMINE -> MINE1 -> MINE2 -> MINE3 -> MINE4 -> MINE5

I tried to squash MINE1-4 into MINE5, but ended up squashing them into NOTMINE.

I ran `git rebase -i HEAD~5` and set it to pick MINE5 and squash MINE1-4.

In order to fix this I tried `git reflog` and based on that I ran `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`, which looked like the moment before the squash, but that had no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: check `git reflog` for desired state

Comment: Is there any way to get more info about the states in `git reflog`? Because to be honest I'm not sure which one represents what I want.

Comment: @mu234 some GUI tools are handy for the reflog. For example TortoiseGit (Windows) has a nice reflog view.  https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reflog.html

Comment: Use the ref log to find the reference of MINE5 before the rebase and then reset hard to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your reflog.

One line should indicate the beginning of your rebase :

```
<sha> HEAD@{xx} rebase (start): checkout <something>
```

(since you asked for `git rebase -i HEAD~5`, `<something>` will probably be an explicit sha1 ;
when you ask for a named ref as in `git rebase -i origin/master`, the log mentions that name)

The line *below* that one (`<sha> HEAD@{xx+1}`) is the commit you are looking for.